# Dynamic client registration with Google's OAUTH2 (RFC7591)

Tags: google-oauth

Does Google's OAUTH2 implementation support dynamic client registration, as described in RFC7591? If so, I've been unable to find anything which says it does (or does not,) and in particular can't find any mention of a client registration endpoint to use. I would like to use it for a desktop (native) application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not allow for programmatically creating Oauth clients on their authorization server.

Creating and configuring of your project on google cloud console as well as creating client credentials, configuring the oauth2 consent screen and the clients themselves

must be done manually by the developer on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/).

> I've been unable to find anything which says it does (or does not,)

Typically one does not document what is not possible only what is possible.  Documentation would be very large indeed if they tried to mention everything that they don't allow.

By that logic normally if you cant find something its because its not supported.   Wouldn't it be great if it was though

Comment: I wasn't seriously expecting a definitive "not supported" but hoped for something that maybe hinted at it, not just in Google's own docs, but in other resources. Thanks for answering.

Comment: There is or was a very limited api which allowed for listing the projects you have on google cloud console.  It had no other functionality then that you couldn't create anything.   I wrote a blog post on it years ago cant seem to find it or remember the name of it.   It may have just gone away.

Comment: Found it https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-api/  I think this is the closest you are going to get.

Comment: That seems to address a different problem. With static client registration it is necessary to embed a pre-obtained client id and secret (which I currently have) in the application. No matter how you try to obfuscate them, they can be extracted, especially with languages like Java and C# which can readily be decompiled into human readable source code. Dynamic registration gives each client its own id, thereby avoiding the need to hardcode an identity.

Comment: Unless its compiled within your application you cant give it to anyone else.  Google accepts that installed applications can be decompiled there is really no other option unless you want to put up a web server and host it for your desktop app.  done that its not optimal if the user is offline.   Remember if you expect others to register their own clients then they are going to have to go though the verification process themselves.